# Start Up Windows Server 2012 Virtual Machine in Windows Azure Automatically at 7AM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

One of the virtual machines I have on Windows Azure only needs to be available 12 hours per day each weekday.  I am connecting to a database and running some analysis.  Considering they charge for compute hours, it would be nice if I wasn't charged for the time the VM is sitting idle.  I have found a method to auto shut down at a specific time, but I can't find a way to automatically start up the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run a startup script, outside of the VM itself (either directly via REST API, via PowerShell, or via cross-platform CLI). You can run this pretty much anywhere (on-premises server; another Azure VM; etc.). Or, you could use the Mobile Services scheduler, and have a task run every x hours or y days. The script, written in node.js, has access to the `azure` module, which should then let you make a management call to start a vm. You can see docs around VM management in node, [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/computeManagement/README.md).

If you're running a scheduler / timer anywhere else, you can call either a PowerShell cmdlet or an Azure CLI script (installable on Windows/Mac/Linux) to start a VM. You can do the same procedure to shut it down, or leave the VM as-is, and let it shut itself down.

Comment: Thanks David - I am planning on digging through your web site later!  I have read some conflicting answers related to how Microsoft charges for compute hours for Azure VMs.  If the VM is stopped (deallocated), we are not charged per compute hour?  Only when the VM is started?  Thank you for the assistance with this.

Comment: Virtual Machines are billed by the minute (based on an hourly rate, with I believe a 10-minute minimum). If you stop a VM, you are not charged (aside from the storage the disks take up). If you stop all VMs in a cloud service (e.g. all VMs inside `xyz.cloudapp.net`), then you'll lose your assigned VIP. If you want to *keep* the assigned VIP, you need to leave at least one VM running, or stop the last VM but continue to pay.

Comment: David, as the kids say these days, or at least the kids 10 years ago, you are the bomb dot com.  I checked to see if I could reserve that domain name for you, but it was already registered...under your name!!